# finding which div was clicked when click event is on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs under class subcat. And I have a click event on the class. I want to get the div which was clicked.

```
<div class="subcat"><a href="#">abc</div>
<div class="subcat"><a href="#">def</div>
<div class="subcat"><a href="#">ghi</div>
<div class="subcat"><a href="#">jkl</div>
```

My jquery function is like

```
$('.subcat').click(function(element) {
    element.preventDefault();
    getsubcat(element);
});
```

But the element shows null. I tried using this instead of element but that didn't work either.

```
$('.subcat').click(function(element) {
    this.preventDefault();
    getsubcat(this);
});
```

I had earlier written it as below and it was working perfectly well.

```
<div class="subcat"><a href="#" onclick="getsubcat(this)">abc</div>
<div class="subcat"><a href="#" onclick="getsubcat(this)">def</div>
<div class="subcat"><a href="#" onclick="getsubcat(this)">ghi</div>
<div class="subcat"><a href="#" onclick="getsubcat(this)">jkl</div>
```

Comment: You pass the event not the element in the function

Comment: `element.target` could be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter to the event handler is the `event` object, so you need to call `preventDefault()` on that.

`this` inside the event handler will point to the dom element to which the handler was registered to, so that can be passed to `getsubcat`

```
$('.subcat').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    getsubcat(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass the element you pass the event, same goes for preventing default, once clicked this or $(this) references the element that was clicked.

```
$('.subcat').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        getsubcat($(this));
    });
```

Comment: don't pass `$(this)` as it looks like `getsubcat` is expecting a dom element reference

Comment: @ArunPJohny hmm in that case `this` would be the way or `$(this)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.subcat').click(function(element) {
    element.preventDefault();
    getsubcat($(this));
});
```

Comment: don't pass `$(this)` as it looks like `getsubcat` is expecting a dom element reference